# How do I preserve side data when concatenating files in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, transcoding, 360-video

I have multiple 360 videos that I'm trying to concatenate in ffmpeg.  The command it self is pretty straightforward:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i 0036_concat.txt -c copy -strict unofficial 36.mp4
```

where `0036_concat.txt` is just a list of the individual files.  The issue I'm having is that I can't get ffmpeg to preserve side data.  Very simply put, `ffprobe` on any of the source files includes this:

```
Side data:
  spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)
```

And I can't, for the life of me, get that to propagate to the output file.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760588/preserving-side-data-information-for-360-video-transcoding-using-ffmpeg) has a solution that works for single files, but it doesn't work when concatenating multiple files.

I'd be perfectly fine injecting that entire string if anyone knows how.

Comment: Can you provide a link to one of the individual files listed in `0036_concat.txt`?

Comment: @llogan -- File contents are just `file 'name.mp4'\nfile 'name2.mp4'`, etc

Comment: @llogan -- my bad, misread that.  Here's a 1 sec clip: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qntwf6m85sxvar9/GS020101.mp4?dl=0

Comment: See if this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11706049/converting-video-formats-and-copying-tags-with-ffmpeg/50580239#50580239

Comment: @TarunLalwani -- Unfortunately not.  I've seen that answer before and don't understand why it doesn't work, I'm guessing this isn't actually "metadata" according to ffmpeg.  There's almost zero documentation on side data

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `ffmpeg` doesn't support that. Many people suggest developing your own extension for FFmpeg, but i found it overkill.

Instead, **I have successfully done it** using `google spatialmedia` to add the side data to the output video resulting from the FFmpeg concat. It is as simple as

```
python spatialmedia -i 36.mp4  equirectangular.mp4
```

You can get spatialmedia from its [official repo](https://github.com/google/spatial-media). Download [the latest release](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/archive/v2.1.zip), unzip it, and you will be able to run the above command directly.

In case you don't have it, you need to install [python](http://python.org) first.

**That is all you need.**

---

Bellow I add an example in my local with your own video.

I downloaded your [sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qntwf6m85sxvar9/GS020101.mp4?dl=0), and created the below file list

[image]

Run `ffprobe GS020101.mp4`, we can see that `Side data: spherical: equirectangular (0.000000/0.000000/0.000000)` is there

[image]

Run `ffmpeg -f concat -i 0036_concat.txt -c copy -strict unofficial output.mp4`

Run `ffprobe output.mp4`, as you expected, side data is not there

[image]

Run `python spatialmedia -i output.mp4 equirectangular.mp4`

[image]

Run `ffprobe equirectangulat.mp4`, **this time you can see successfully the expected side data**.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't actually answer the question.  I'm aware of the spatial media injector, but I not everything I have is equirecangular so it doesn't work

Comment: This is the only answer I have found so far that allowed me to get a badly stitched 360 video uploaded to YouTube. Thanks! Just need to work on my stitching problem!

Answer (score 4):

Although it seems like ffmpeg doesn't support this, I found that [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/) seems to do the job. Run this command after your ffmpeg concat:

```
exiftool -tagsFromFile first_file_inside_concat_file.mp4 -all:all 36.mp4
```